# How to select first nested element

Tags: jquery, node.js

I am trying to use cheerioJS, which should have the same selectors as JQuery. I therefore ask the question for JQuery.

I have an html code with nested span tags where there might be arbitrary tags between the nested spans. I.e.

```
<span>
 <p>
  <span>
   <p>
    <span>
     ...
```

I am interested in selecting the second only. I can select the first using

```
$(span).not("span span")
```

I can also select the second and third using

```
$(span).not("span span").find("span")
```

But I do not manage to select the second one only. I tried:

```
$(span).not("span span").find("span").not("span span")
```

or

```
$(span).not("span span").find("span").not("span span",$(span).not("span span"))
```

But I still fail to get the required result. Is there a way around it? If not, is there a way to traverse children recursively until getting to the second element? I.e. more JS code and less JQuery?

Thank you.

Comment: What about `$(span).next("span")`?

Comment: The first thing you have to fix is the invalid markup. You can't have a `p` element inside a `span`. When you do so, the `p` element may be relocated in the DOM to make the DOM valid. So you can't rely on where the `p` will be relative to the `span`.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava - `next` does siblings, not children or descendants.

Comment: In fiddle, creating  paragraphs tags within  paragraph tag causing issue in rendered html. weird.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` and `eq` selector. `find` will check all child span element and you can mention order using `eq` as below:

```
$(span).find("span").eq(1);
```

Here `1` will refer to second `span` under `$(span)` container. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didnt know about eq which can solve the problem in some situations. It cannot distinguish (if I understand correctly) between different levels of nesting and therefore cannot solve my problem in the general case. Thank you for the answer again anyway.